# How to re-index all subarray elements of a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, reindex

The question is how to reset key e.g. for an array:

```
Array ( 
    [1_Name] => Array ( 
        [1] => leo 
        [4] => NULL 
    ) 
    [1_Phone] => Array ( 
        [1] => 12345 
        [4] => 434324
    )  
)
```

reset to :

```
Array ( 
    [1_Name] => Array ( 
        [0] => leo 
        [1] => NULL 
    ) 
    [1_Phone] => Array ( 
        [0] => 12345 
        [1] => 434324
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Check this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943149/rebase-array-keys-after-unsetting-elements/24332702#24332702

Answer (score 347, accepted):

To reset the keys of all arrays in an array:

```
$arr = array_map('array_values', $arr);
```

In case you just want to reset first-level array keys, use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) without [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Comment: Didn't reset the keys of my array for some reason, had to use just the `array_values` function.

Comment: @SSH Did you use it on an *array of arrays*, as was called for here?

Comment: Nope that was the problem, I thought this was supposed to "Reset the keys of array elements", it doesn't.

Comment: you dont need to use array_map: $ret = array_values($ret); is enough to reset numeric keys

Comment: @Marek Not if you need to reset the keys of *arrays in arrays*.

Comment: I dont know if the use of array_values for resetting values is documented, but it should be. This really helped cut down on the number of lines I was writing :)

Answer (score 241):

```
$array[9] = 'Apple';
$array[12] = 'Orange';
$array[5] = 'Peach';

$array = array_values($array);
```

through this function you can reset your array

```
$array[0] = 'Apple';
$array[1] = 'Orange';
$array[2] = 'Peach';
```

Answer (score 24):

Use `array_values` to reset keys

```
foreach($input as &$val) {
   $val = array_values($val);
}
```

http://php.net/array_values

Answer (score 11):

Here you can see the difference between the way that [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) offered comparing to the simple `array_values` approach:

The Array:

```
$array['a'][0] = array('x' => 1, 'y' => 2, 'z' => 3);
$array['a'][5] = array('x' => 4, 'y' => 5, 'z' => 6);

$array['b'][1] = array('x' => 7, 'y' => 8, 'z' => 9);
$array['b'][7] = array('x' => 10, 'y' => 11, 'z' => 12);
```

In `deceze` way, here is your output:

```
$array = array_map('array_values', $array);
print_r($array);

/* Output */

Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 1
                    [y] => 2
                    [z] => 3
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 4
                    [y] => 5
                    [z] => 6
                )
        )
    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 7
                    [y] => 8
                    [z] => 9
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 10
                    [y] => 11
                    [z] => 12
                )
        )
)
```

And here is your output if you only use `array_values` function:

```
$array = array_values($array);
print_r($array);

/* Output */

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 1
                    [y] => 2
                    [z] => 3
                )
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 4
                    [y] => 5
                    [z] => 6
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 7
                    [y] => 8
                    [z] => 9
                )
            [7] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 10
                    [y] => 11
                    [z] => 12
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$result = ['5' => 'cherry', '7' => 'apple'];
array_multisort($result, SORT_ASC);
print_r($result);
```

Array ( [0] => apple [1] => cherry )

```
//...
array_multisort($result, SORT_DESC);
//...
```

Array ( [0] => cherry [1] => apple )

Answer (score -7):

PHP native function exists for this. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

Simply do this: `mixed reset ( array &$array )`

Comment: Please do read the manual you're linking to; `reset` does something else.

Comment: It's just move pointer to first element of array. Topicstarter searching way to drop keys in default state 0, 1, 2...N.