# array_map triple dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-map

How do I run a array_map on a triple dimensional array? Where I want to "clear" the innermost array?

It looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [cat] => Hello!
                    [url] => hello
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [cat] => Good job!
                    [url] => good-job
                )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [cat] => How are you?
                    [url] => how-are-you
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [cat] => Running shoes
                    [url] => running-shoes
                )
        )
)
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [cat] => Hello!
                    [url] => hello
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [cat] => Good job!
                    [url] => good-job
                )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [cat] => How are you?
                    [url] => how-are-you
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [cat] => Running shoes
                    [url] => running-shoes
                )
        )
```

)

This solution [Reset keys of array elements in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492839/reset-keys-of-array-elements-in-php) "just" works on tow diemensional arrays, if Im not wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you want the arrays numbered `1` and `2`, not `0` and `1`?

Comment: You call just implement the re-keying within a loop. @JohnSmith  Use as many loops as you need to to access the appropriate level.  We don't necessarily need a new question on SO for every array depth where `array_values()` should be called.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a short function to do it with array_map:

```
function mappingfunction($array){
    $remappedarray = array();
    foreach($array as $layer){
        $remappedarray[] = array_map('array_values', $array);
    }

    return $remappedarray;
}
```

if you want to preserve the keys:

```
function mappingfunction($array){
        $remappedarray = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $layer){
            $remappedarray[$key] = array_map('array_values', $array);
        }

        return $remappedarray;
    }
```

Untested, but should point you in the right direction.