# Ordering and converting a numeric index array that begins with [0] in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a numeric index array.

It can begin with any number, and then go on a hundred times.

I would rather have it ordered.

Example:

```
$myarray = array();

$myarray[500] = 2;
$myarray[501] = 3;
```

Should be:

```
$myarray[0] = 2;
$myarray[1] = 3;
```

I know I could do this with a `foreach`:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($myarray as $key => $value){
$myarray[$i] = $value;
$i++
}
```

Is there any function for this in PHP?

Comment: `$myarray = array_values($myarray);`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Perfect. You might want to add it as an answer.

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492839/reset-keys-of-array-elements-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with [array_value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$myArray  = array_values($myArray);
```

Array_value will reset the key numerically and returns all the values from the array.