# PHP: Associative array to numeric array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have the following problem:

I have a 2-dimentional array containing some data, the first index contains the "year" and in the second has a range with values on it.

Here's an example of how a regular data is parsed though `print_r()`.

```
Array
(
    [2017] => Array
        (
            [0] => 215
            [1] => 182
            [2] => 149
            [3] => 159
            [4] => 176
            [5] => 151
            [6] => 221
            [7] => 185
            [8] => 178
            [9] => 191
            [10] => 265
            [11] => 304
        )

    [2016] => Array
        (
            [0] => 162
            [1] => 179
            [2] => 162
            [3] => 201
            [4] => 169
            [5] => 148
            [6] => 139
            [7] => 139
            [8] => 149
            [9] => 187
            [10] => 264
            [11] => 229
        )
}
```

It works well in this case. I'm using `json_encode()` from PHP and `JSON.parse()` to send the array to JavaScript.

However, there's a particular case that's not working well enough.

```
[2015] => Array
    (
        [1] => 4
        [6] => 88
        [7] => 119
        [8] => 117
        [9] => 107
        [10] => 151
        [11] => 218
    )
```

This array is being interpreted as a associative array, so JavaScript interprets as an `Object` datatype. My external library expect an array so it throws an error and the JavaScript execution halts.

When I try to fill the missing data in between with zeroes with this method

```
foreach($eM_value as $key => $value)
{
    for($x = 0;$x <= 11;$x++)
        $eM_value[$key][$x] = ((isset($eM_value[$key][$x])) ? intval($eM_value[$key][$x]) : 0);
}
```

It still is interpreted as an associative array.

```
[2015] => Array
    (
        [1] => 4
        [6] => 88
        [7] => 119
        [8] => 117
        [9] => 107
        [10] => 151
        [11] => 218
        [0] => 0
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0
    )
```

How can I convert this specific entry to a numeric array?

If more information is needed please comment and I'll add it.

Comment: `ksort` the array.

Comment: This will work YW https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492839/reset-keys-of-array-elements-in-php

Comment: if you have "holes" in the numerical keys, it's far better to understand it as an object in JS, or else you'll have a bunch of undefined elements filling the holes. Arrays cannot have holes in JS.

Comment: try creating a new array and not reusing $eM_value

Comment: create new array before json_encode. use array_values to get ranges without index gaps. `foreach($array as $year => $ranges) { newArray[$year] = array_values($ranges)}` And json_encode new array

Comment: `ksort()` method worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_fill` to prepare a placeholder array and then `array_replace` to put the real data in:

```
<?php

$input = [
    1 => 10,
    3 => 12,
    5 => 54
];

$output = array_replace(array_fill(0, 12, 0), $input);
print_r($output);
```

Will give you:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => 0 
   [1] => 10 
   [2] => 0 
   [3] => 12 
   [4] => 0 
   [5] => 54 
   [6] => 0 
   [7] => 0 
   [8] => 0 
   [9] => 0 
   [10] => 0 
   [11] => 0 
)
```

This way you can avoid sorting the keys.

Answer (score 2):

just use `array_values` function in PHP, it will output a numeric array of all the values