# how to remove a parent index array and change it to object in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array like below :

```
array:3 [
  "2021-08-07" => array:3 [
    "id" => "1"
    "date" => "2021-08-07"
    "numbers" => array:2 [
      0 => 1
      1 => 2
    ]
  ]
  "2021-08-08" => array:3 [
    "id" => "1"
    "date" => "2021-08-08"
    "numbers" => array:2 [
      0 => 1
      1 => 2
    ]
  ]
]
```

What I want to do is simply to remote the parent `2021-08-08` items because I have the date inside the array already . Now, what I have tried so far is :

```
$result = array_map(function ($el){
    return $el[0];
},$test);

dd($result);
```

But it gives me error of `undefined index[0]` . what I want this array to look like is like below :

```
array:3 [
    "id" => "1"
    "date" => "2021-08-07"
    "numbers" => array:2 [
      0 => 1
      1 => 2
  ],
    "id" => "1"
    "date" => "2021-08-08"
    "numbers" => array:2 [
      0 => 1
      1 => 2
  ]
]
```

Comment: You can also use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10492870/6212294)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't just [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values) do?

```php
array_values($test);
```

Comment: that was so ez lol :) thanks for help that was the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
$test = array_values(yourArray);
$test = (object)$yourArray;
```