# How to get difference of two arrays without association in php

Tags: php, arrays, difference

My first array A is : `["1604","1606","1610"]`

My second Array B is : `["1604","1606","1607","1610"]`

But when i am executing :

```
   $results= array_diff($b,$a);
```

then I got the result like this But i dont want association (i.e. 2 as below). I want only key.(i.e. 1607).

**My output Array results is : {"2":"1607"}**

**I want output like ["1607"].**

Comment: You need to [rebase the array key values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5943165/561731)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there, just one more step: `array_values($results)`

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the values of the result:

```
$results= array_values(array_diff($b,$a));
```

Answer (score 0):

To a double-sided array_diff use

```
$result = array_values(array_merge(array_diff($b, $a), array_diff($a, $b)));
```

if not use

```
$result = array_values(array_diff($b, $a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$results = array_values(array_diff($b,$a))
```

In PHP, all arrays are associative.  array_values essentially "resets" the indexes to a numeric version.