# php how to sort/serialize array keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am not sure if these are the correct words to express my query.
I have the following array, result of filtration stage. As you can see the keys are not consecutive [e.g. 2,3,5,7 etc]. is there any php function that will automatically re-structure the keys for me (like, the first key is 0 and then consecutive 1,2,3 etc.)?
sort() function does not help and I also tried several other PHP array sorting functions but none helped.

```
Array
(
    [2] => RP/
    [3] => LONU1
    [5] => 1.ISL
    [7] => 2.KHO
    [9] => 3.KHO
    [11] => 4.RUMA/
    [12] => 5  EK
    [13] => 6  EK 582
    [14] => 7  E
    [15] => 8  EK 011 L
)
```

Comment: `array_values` maybe?  `sort` would have done it, of course it would have also sorted.

Comment: @AbraCadaver : Yes, that's right. `array_values()` has done it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) is your friend.

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943165/1415625)