# How to reset keys after unsetting values in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Take the following array:

```
$fruits = [
    'apple', 'banana', 'grapefruit', 'orange', 'melon'
];
```

Grapefruits are just disgusting, so I would like to unset it.

```
$key = array_search('grapefruit', $fruit);
unset($fruit[$key]);
```

The grapefruit is out of my `$fruit` array but my keys are no longer numbered correctly.

```
array(4) {
    [0] => 'apple'
    [1] => 'banana'
    [3] => 'orange'
    [4] => 'melon'
}
```

I Could loop through the array and create a new one but I was wondering if there's a simpler method to reset the keys.

Comment: There is.... [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: 3.5k rep and I found your duplicate target by just googling "php reset array keys"

Comment: @Epodax You could have looked in the Related bar as well :-)

Comment: @jeroen Only makes it that much worse for OP.

Comment: What I use in similar situations is `$arr = array_merge( $arr );`. You can see my answer to a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55048335/673846.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
array_values( $array );
```

Test Results:

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
<?php

$fruits = [
    'apple', 'banana', 'grapefruit', 'orange', 'melon'
];

$key = array_search('grapefruit', $fruits);
unset($fruits[$key]);

// before
print_r($fruits);

//after
print_r(array_values($fruits));
?>
```

Execution:

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => banana
    [3] => orange
    [4] => melon
)
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => banana
    [2] => orange
    [3] => melon
)
```