# How can I reset array key and shift first key to 1 in php?

Tags: php

I found a similar question but it doesn't full fill what I need
[How to reset keys after unsetting values in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602299/how-to-reset-keys-after-unsetting-values-in-an-array)

my array is like

```
$fruits = array(
 [0] => 'apple'
 [1] => 'banana'
 [3] => 'orange'
 [4] => 'melon'
);
```

With array_values I can reset it starting from 0

```
array_values($fruits);

// array fixed 
array(4) {
 [0] => 'apple'
 [1] => 'banana'
 [2] => 'orange'
 [3] => 'melon'
}
```

But I need to reset starting from 1 instead 0, is it possible?

```
// array fixed
array(4) {
 [1] => 'apple'
 [2] => 'banana'
 [3] => 'orange'
 [4] => 'melon'
}
```

Comment: array always start with `0` .. make a `foreach loop` with an iteration and assign a new array yourself starting with `1`

Comment: `array_combine(range(1,count($fruits)),$fruits);`

Comment: Why would you want to do this? As pointed out above, normal arrays start at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following code.

```
function reindex ($arr, $start_index)
{
    $arr = array_combine(range($start_index,  count($arr) + ($start_index - 1)), array_values($arr)); 
    return $arr;
}
```

Following is my test result.

```
$arr = array ( 
    0 => 'apple', 
    1 => 'banana', 
    3 => 'orange',  
    4 => 'melon' 
); 

$arr = reindex ($arr, 1);

foreach( $arr as $key => $value) {  
    echo "Index: ".$key." Value: ".$value."\n";  
}
```

And following is the output.

```
Index: 1 Value: apple
Index: 2 Value: banana
Index: 3 Value: orange
Index: 4 Value: melon
```

You can test this code on following online tester.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding 1 to key:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     $array[$key+1] = $array[$key];
     unset($array[$key];
}
```

But its working just when your array starts with 0 key.

That you can do with:
    array_values($array);

Comment: Your answer give me an idea so i whent like:

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
         echo $key+1 ." = ". $array[$key];
         unset($array[$key];
    }