# how can I avoid json_encode adding key values to my array objects?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following json data

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "thingA": "aaaaaa",
      "thingB": "bbbbbb",
      "thingC": "cccccc",
      "thingD": {
        "thingD1": "d1d1d1d1",
        "thingD2": "d2d2d2d2"
      },
      "thingE": "eeeeee",
      "out_file": "ffffff"
    },
{
      "thingA": "aaaaaa",
      "thingB": "bbbbbb",
      "thingC": "cccccc",
      "thingD": {
        "thingD1": "d1d1d1d1",
        "thingD2": "d2d2d2d2"
      },
      "thingE": "eeeeee",
      "out_file": "ffffff"
    },
{
      "thingA": "aaaaaa",
      "thingB": "bbbbbb",
      "thingC": "cccccc",
      "thingD": {
        "thingD1": "d1d1d1d1",
        "thingD2": "d2d2d2d2"
      },
      "thingE": "eeeeee",
      "out_file": "ffffff"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm attempting to convert this to an array in PHP using json_decode, remove an item from the array based on the array position / index, then convert the array back to JSON using json_encode.

To modify the array, im using the following PHP command

```
unset($configuration_Array->{'apps'}[$i]);
```

Where $i is the index position of the item being removed.

it's all working almost perfectly except that in the final (output) JSON data, I noticed I get key values added  to each "apps" object (note the 'number key before each object')

```
{
  "apps":{
    "1":{
      "thingA":"aaaaaa",
      "thingB":"bbbbbb",
      "thingC":"cccccc",
      "thingD":{
        "thingD1":"d1d1d1d1",
        "thingD2":"d2d2d2d2"
      },
      "thingE":"eeeeee",
      "out_file":"ffffff"
    },
    "2":{
      "thingA":"aaaaaa",
      "thingB":"bbbbbb",
      "thingC":"cccccc",
      "thingD":{
        "thingD1":"d1d1d1d1",
        "thingD2":"d2d2d2d2"
      },
      "thingE":"eeeeee",
      "out_file":"ffffff"
    },
    "3":{
      "thingA":"aaaaaa",
      "thingB":"bbbbbb",
      "thingC":"cccccc",
      "thingD":{
        "thingD1":"d1d1d1d1",
        "thingD2":"d2d2d2d2"
      },
      "thingE":"eeeeee",
      "out_file":"ffffff"
    }        
  }
}
```

How can I avoid this being added when I perform json_encode or after the fact, remove it so that the data is structured exactly like the original version?

Comment: Could you show the code you use to modify the array?

Comment: You likely need to rebase the array before converting back to JSON, see this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943149/rebase-array-keys-after-unsetting-elements

Comment: @TecBrat its been marked as duplicate but I edited and added details on what I'm doing to the array