# Delete object from json file with PHP

Tags: php, json

Well, I have a web project and I have to be saving things temporarily, I started work with a json file, so far I can add and update. 
The json file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "username": "Baldwin",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "amount": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "amount": 9
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "amount": 9
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username": "Alice",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "amount": 11
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "amount": 13
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "amount": 6
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username": "Terry",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "amount": 12
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "amount": 14
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "amount": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The problem comes when I want to delete an specific array or when I want to delete it completely, I can do it and it works fine, but I have the doubt about why when I delete the object, other fields are add to the json file, like an id.

When i delete just one product inside of the "products" array something like this happen:

```
[
  {
    "username": "Baldwin",
    "products": { "1": { "id": 1, "amount": 9 }, "2": { "id": 2, "amount": 9 } }
  },
  {
    "username": "Alice",
    "products": [
      { "id": 0, "amount": 11 },
      { "id": 1, "amount": 13 },
      { "id": 2, "amount": 6 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username": "Terry",
    "products": [
      { "id": 0, "amount": 12 },
      { "id": 1, "amount": 14 },
      { "id": 2, "amount": 5 }
    ]
  }
]
```

And when i delete a complete array from the json file, something like this happen:

```
{
  "1": {
    "username": "Alice",
    "products": [
      { "id": 0, "amount": 11 },
      { "id": 1, "amount": 13 },
      { "id": 2, "amount": 6 }
    ]
  },
  "2": {
    "username": "Terry",
    "products": [
      { "id": 0, "amount": 12 },
      { "id": 1, "amount": 14 },
      { "id": 2, "amount": 5 }
    ]
  }
}
```

My php file to delete:

```
<?php 

    // load file
    $data = file_get_contents('results.json');

    // decode json to associative array
    $json_arr = json_decode($data, true);

    $flag = false;
    // We check if the user wants to delete all or just one product
    if(isset($_POST["all"])):

        $username = $_POST["username"];

        foreach ($json_arr as $key => $value):

            // find the username on the json file
            if($value["username"] == $username):

                unset($json_arr[$key]);
                break;

            endif;

        endforeach; 

    elseif(isset($_POST["one"])):

        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $id = $_POST["id"];

        foreach ($json_arr as $key => $value):

            // find the username on the json file
            if($value["username"] == $username):

                // loop products of the current username
                foreach ($json_arr[$key]["products"] as $k => $product):

                    // find the id of the product 
                    if($json_arr[$key]["products"][$k]["id"] == (int)$id):

                        // delete the product
                        unset($json_arr[$key]["products"][$k]);

                    endif;

                endforeach;

            endif;

        endforeach; 

    endif;

     // encode json and save to file
    file_put_contents('results.json', json_encode($json_arr));

    // redirect to show.php
    header("Location: show.php");
?>
```

I've been taking a look to questions like this one but i couldn't find something with php, i would like to know how to solve this or if this is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when you use `unset($json_arr[0])` is that the first element is removed, but the keys are not updated. If you inspect the array after the removal, you'll find that your array has two elements, at `$json_arr[1]` and `$json_arr[2]`.

When you then perform a `json_encode($json_arr)` on this, PHP's JSON decoder looks at the array and since arrays are supposed to begin at the `0`th element but this array begins at `1`, it decides that in order to preserve the keys, the array would have to be converted to an associative array - which transforms the integer array keys into string keys in JSON.

For a short and quick solution, you can try:

```
$json_arr = array_diff($json_arr, [$key]);
```

You could even use `array_splice` or `array_values` - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943149/rebase-array-keys-after-unsetting-elements) for inspiration.

Comment: I get it, but still, i tried with the code and that throw me an error:
Notice: Array to string conversion in line 21 that is where i put the line of code.

Comment: I was going to say that maybe you were using `$key` instead of `[$key]`. But I'm glad it works for you now. In any case, the relevant lines of code should've been replaced with `$json_arr = array_diff($json_arr, [$key]);` and `$json_arr = array_diff($json_arr[$key]["products"], [$k]);` respectively.

Comment: Oh yeah, i was using `$key` instead of `[$key]`, that solve the problem as well. Thanks!!