# Capture specific value from df -h --total using PHP

Tags: php, linux-disk-free

How can i populate a variable holding the total value from below content extracted after running `df -h --total` on centos. Note: *the result is not from command line but from a php file.*

How do i only capture the percentage value in the last line using PHP?

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root 20G 685M 20G 4% /
devtmpfs 40G 0 40G 0% /dev
tmpfs 40G 0 40G 0% /dev/shm
tmpfs 40G 177M 40G 1% /run
tmpfs 40G 0 40G 0% /sys/fs/cg
/dev/mapper/rhel-usr 20G 3.2G 17G 16% /usr
/dev/sda2 1014M 223M 792M 22% /boot
/dev/mapper/rhel-opt_mycom 100G 37G 63G 37% /opt/my
/dev/mapper/oradb-nimsdb 2.0T 1.5T 614G 71% /opt/my/data
/dev/mapper/redo-logs 305G 72G 234G 24% /opt/my/data/
/dev/mapper/rhel-home 20G 472M 20G 3% /home
/dev/mapper/rhel-var 20G 1.4G 19G 7% /var
tmpfs 7.9G 0 7.9G 0% /run/user/1000
total 3.6T 2.3T 1.4T 63% -
```

I.E. i would want a variable that has the value 63%

```
$variable = 63%
```

Comment: How are you running the command?

Comment: ` $result = $ssh->exec('df -h --total');` I am running from a php file

Comment: Try [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead to capture the output and then play with the string to grab what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `grep` and `awk` to extract the info you want:

```
$result = $ssh->exec("df -h --total | grep '^total ' | awk '{print $5}'");
```

Note that you need to change the types of quoting you are doing for this to work properly. Just copy and paste the above and you should be good.

Comment: Nice answer, Can we improve the answer further so that we just capture the digit with the percentage?

Comment: Intval is nice way of fetching int value but in this case i only need the one that has a percentage value. It is returning a zero result

Comment: @OmariVictorOmosa - Ah, I understand what you are saying now. I will update.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can adapt this snippet for your needs:

```php
$data = <<<EOF
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
ubi0_0                  143180     89740     53440  63% /
tmpfs                       64         0        64   0% /dev
tmpfs                   143124        76    143048   0% /tmp
tmpfs                     4096       912      3184  22% /var
tmpfs                       64         0        64   0% /mnt
ubi1_0                  468256     12144    456112   3% /opt/data/settings
EOF;

print_r(array_map(function($line){
    $elements=preg_split('/\s+/',$line);
    return(array(
    'filesystem' => $elements[0],
    '1k-blocks' => $elements[1],
    'used' => $elements[2],
    'available' => $elements[3],
    'use%' => $elements[4],
    'mounted_on' => $elements[5]
    ));
},explode("\n",$data)));
```

https://gist.github.com/cschaba/4740323

Comment: I wish you could explain further

Answer (score 1):

sorry if i misunderstood the question how ever i think this could be the answer you are looking for... :)

**Version 1:**

```
#executes the comand and stores in array
$testExec = exec("df -h --total" ,$testArray);
#moves to the end off the array
$testArrayEnd = end($testExec);
#splits the last line into an array
$stringArray = explode(' ',$testArrayEnd);
foreach($stringArray as $string){
    #checks if the string contains a % 
    if (preg_match("/%/", $string)) {
        #there is only one % so this is what you're looking for
        $percentage = $string;
        var_dump($percentage);
    }
}
```

PS. @ReynierPM you don't require a shell_exec to get a full output return... you just have to define a array where you want to store the data in... :) and granted its not a string but you could easily transform it into one by using [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php)

**Version 2:**

Sorry If you disagree but i don't feel comfortable just editing @Nazariy answer as I'm adding/changing to much (at this stage see edit history:).

```
#thanks go out to ReynierPM
#returns string with every entry being separated by a newline 
$output = shell_exec('df -h --total');

$ArrayFull=(array_map(function($line){ /*<-- *¹ & *² */
    $elements=preg_split('/\s+/',$line); /*<--- *4  */>
    return(array(
    'filesystem' => $elements[0],
    '1k-blocks' => $elements[1],
    'used' => $elements[2],
    'available' => $elements[3],
    'use%' => $elements[4],
    'mounted_on' => $elements[5]
    ));
},explode("\n",$output))); /*(<--- *³)*/

#removes bloat
unset($ArrayFull[0]);
#Rebase array keys https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943149/rebase-array-keys-after-unsetting-elements
$ArrayFull=array_values($ArrayFull);

#if you only want the last value ;)
$lastVallue = end($ArrayFull);
```

Explanation:

*¹
 [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-map.php) applies it too all values in the array 
    "array_map — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays"

*²
 We first give it a callback function which will be called for every element,        and pass it the variable $line (we use this to store the line created by the explode)
*³
We use the array_maps to explode by \n (to create a array entry for evry new line) (We offcourse do an explode on $data) 
*4
So now that every line is separated... We split the separated lines into substrings and store them in new variables.
preg_split('/\s+/',$line) splitting $line into an array without having to deal with the issue of multiple whitspaces. s standing for space.

Sorry for the formatting... will edit latter :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer since i can get to my final answer having the percentage value. Although i have mixed your answer with @sean_bright. i am going through your version  2 to see if i can learn from

Comment: @OmariVictorOmosa Just glad i could help :) ... To be fair the answer given by sean_bright is just a lot more slick... If you have any further question concerning the code snippet just ask...